# Find what row has horizontal print marquee line

Tags: excel, vba

This is molasses slow (and doesn't work on fresh sheets):

```
Sub Test()
 With Sheets("Sheet1")
  .Select

  For n = 1 To 1000
   If .Rows(n).PageBreak <> xlPageBreakNone Then MsgBox n

   If n = 100 Then Exit Sub
  Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want to do is to find the row of the first page break on a sheet, try this

```
Sub WhereIsPageBreak()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws.HPageBreaks
        If .Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox .Item(1).Location.Row
        Else
            MsgBox "No Page Breaks on this Sheet"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to exit when n= 100 then why the loop till 1000? Also when you open a fresh workbook or use the code on a fresh sheet, you will never find the pagebreak as there will be none. If by "fresh" you mean a workbook which already has a pagebreak inserted then your code will still work.

```
Sub Sample()
  For n = 1 To 100
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(n).PageBreak <> xlPageBreakNone Then MsgBox n
  Next
End Sub
```